# Sort Django Rest Framework JSON Output

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I've been developing a web app on top of Django and I use the Django Rest Framework for my API. There's a model class named Events and my EventsSerializer in DRF is a pretty common serializer without any special configuration. It just dumps data returned by the EventManager.

There is a field "type" in the Event model class.
My json returned now is:

```
{
    events: [
      {object1},
      {object2},
      .....
    ]
}
```

, as anything dumped in a DRF api and returned by django.

For some reason, I need my events objects returned categorized by the "type" field. For example, I need to get this:

```
{
    events: [
        type1: [{object1}, {object2},...],
        type2: [{object3}, {object4}, ...],
        .......
    ]
}
```

I have literally searched anything related to that but couldn't find a proper solution. Do you have anything to suggest about that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post code for your serializers, models and views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SerializerMethodField and provide custom serialization logic there:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    events = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source="get_events")

    def get_events(self, events):
        event_list = {}
        return [event_list[e.type].add({e}) if event.type in event_list else event_list[event.type] = [] for event in events]
```

Comment: Assuming I follow this suggestion, which is literally good, I have to create a separate serializer, given that all event fields should be exposed. But I need to avoid making an extra API call, by the time there's an events' serializer already in place

Comment: I didn't get it Can you be more specific?

Comment: @koslib To reduce the database call use `.filter, select_related and prefetch_related` in queryset.

Comment: i suppose you mean the queryset inside the equivalent api view set, right?

Comment: @koslib I meant about the queryset inside the api views

Answer (score 0):

I had a model similar to the following:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

The JSON that was being generated for an `Author` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "Sir Arthur C. Clarke",
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "Rendezvous with Rama",
    },
    {
      "title": "Childhood's End",
    }
  ]
}
```

In the JSON wanted the books to be sorted by title.  Since the books are pulled into the queryset via a `prefetch_related` adding an `order_by` to the View's queryset had no effect (generated SQL didn't have a join to the Books table).  The solution I came up with was to override the `get` method.  In my version of the `get` method, I have the super class generate the `Response` and I modify it's data (a Python `dict`) before returning it as shown below.

I'm not too worried about performance for two reasons:

1. because of the `prefetch_related` the join is already being done in Python rather than in the database
2. In my case the number of `Book`s per `Author` is relatively small

```py
class AuthorView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    queryset = Author.objects.prefetch_related(
        'books',
    )
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

        def key_func(book_json):
            return book_json.get('title', '')

        books = response.data.get('books', [])
        books = sorted(books, key=key_func)
        response.data['books'] = books

        return response
```